# Assessing results from package:IML FeatureImportance function output in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, mgcv

Hello fellow CrossValidated friends!

This question was migrated from StackOverflow, they said StatsCrossValidated was a good place to get an answer. I am trying to understand what it means in terms my grandparents might understand.

I am using the iml package in R to assess the importance of individual variables from a generalized additive model through the featureimportance function (my understanding is that this is something that broadly assesses 'goodness-of-prediction' in place of 'goodness-of-fit).

There is not much documentation showing results of this method. So I ask: Overall, are these results worrisome or trustworthy and deserving of interpretation?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
library(gam)
library(iml)
library(caret)

Mod <- mgcv::gam(v1~
                   s(v2,bs="tp",k=6) + 
                   s(v3,bs="tp",k=6) + 
                   s(v4,bs="tp",k=6)+
                   s(v5,bs="tp",k=6) + 
                   s(v6,bs="tp",k=6) +
                   s(v7,bs="tp",k=6) +
                   s(v8,bs="tp",k=6) +
                   s(v9,bs="tp",k=6) + 
                   s(v10,bs="tp",k=6) +
                   s(v11,m=3,k=6,bs="ps",fx=T),
                 family=quasibinomial(link="logit"),
                 data=df, method="REML",select=T,na.action = na.fail)
summary(Mod)
# approximate R2 to assess variable importance --------------
dfcaret <- caret::varImp(Mod,scale=TRUE)
dfcaret <- rownames_to_column(dfcaret)
dfnew <- dfcaret %>% summarize(newcol = ((Overall/sum(.$Overall))*100)*(summary(Mod)$r.sq))
dfnew
# use IML feature importance to calculate and plot variable importance
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
X = df[,c("V2","V3","V4",
                     "v5","v6","v7",
                     "v8","v9","v10",
                     "v11")]
predictor = Predictor$new(Mod, data = X, y = df$v1)
imp = FeatureImp$new(predictor, loss = "mse", n.repetitions = 1000)
plot(imp)


structure(list(v1 = c(0.589471872900761, 0.538334022066138, 0.544471791430316, 
0.6545521335777, 0.58828167819195, 0.815775495659147, 0.35991545135081, 
0.682005638629792, 0.381793137640682, 0.575075310151926, 0.646314050542596, 
0.545200398156747, 0.554177598037041, 0.548132832393819, 0.585418889166264, 
0.587799621310531, 0.441538909145029, 0.551787446020242, 0.499926596161613, 
0.680905803441033, 0.704358951506874, 0.683064794909415, 0.727992651081849, 
0.523346608220361, 0.621126625680989, 0.650184493371171, 0.589368445319596, 
0.407105375694255, 0.747729210953452, 0.455349205475171, 0.452873590344129, 
0.62917283485195, 0.61506979983509, 0.743862692031867, 0.734020957586681, 
0.417095869926707, 0.60072150579111, 0.472188710467686, 0.306580846831056, 
0.563456157012044, 0.334834011622691, 0.368913122276812, 0.518328799804945, 
0.597383079192756, 0.62817591940884, 0.686999907526581, 0.482711326629372, 
0.527972390145459, 0.708645006584314, 0.658879342853181, 0.644774312555816, 
0.610533970479533, 0.641852599437505, 0.553125694938108, 0.47362996775552, 
0.570974603558188, 0.710883117578292, 0.714112044338371, 0.342754420651065, 
0.51616739327817, 0.548317513895251, 0.590352961366458, 0.492252165301581, 
0.376605216221657, 0.283571956074861, 0.351029008877621, 0.398116760828626, 
0.626803904231991, 0.593357069196078, 0.537187715355588, 0.700748058587519, 
0.525120157564142), v2 = c(61.1227466545568, 81.327970271903, 
202.936933951811, 103.045903656199, 334.441466624615, 43.016206722433, 
1439.13638473691, 125.186425848984, 152.631496772879, 65.0377234347326, 
154.011420104028, 1056.50388478604, 763.121214207733, 803.919945935239, 
1384.42903175386, 1141.38740690275, 1640.876042012, 1530.2677819933, 
245.56511236513, 87.5418337607237, 115.906891885022, 79.707521366091, 
153.112231223452, 1008.23101199042, 96.7893414394331, 52.1468788111021, 
2.8413, 33.5877264325201, 38.9713511927551, 330.949578472656, 
104.097422196485, 69.4066420691014, 3205.23190864467, 274.716773769859, 
819.056489349286, 951.985936951429, 16273.7405283351, 6.12205530709148, 
86.7255348887662, 3286.75448575809, 3663.08101677339, 1787.32772986851, 
30.6660057482306, 77.7376666174115, 85.1255007410538, 464.593866376867, 
1303.63478267342, 368.408517844283, 2072.23470376509, 331.284976667214, 
630.807017561868, 27.6085827018616, 1339.29438854939, 480.313928061242, 
292.840046198777, 1427.34736195971, 488.543760345769, 5680.3802512731, 
100.755749575317, 582.268420236138, 24998.4315540249, 240.309524532195, 
54.66455970641, 40.4771033538894, 30.4398339582898, 16225.8421821948, 
207.803146856566, 32.137347066449, 28994.2800495349, 172.724011039622, 
180.579451733577, 136.883096295627), v3 = c(4.30714439326018, 
0.867465377547213, 1.38609534385876, 1.34668818544517, 1.30054299997543, 
1.73985176698496, 1.53856652042349, 1.58834875300445, 1.47786009843477, 
1.93641938889172, 1.66022697101435, 2.35444220352355, 1.54094003842451, 
2.02670609435515, 1.01654123960454, 0.913149090856051, 2.60371004722423, 
1.50139293034632, 0.954374889216465, 0.977154118406611, 1.45530859779989, 
0.863470076440217, 2.45700243936761, 4.15548753098008, 1.36404513534424, 
1.16040635604206, 0.422244836378517, 0.530127851140233, 1.39514913304127, 
1.23152526408526, 0.806545574881414, 1.14707520371348, 1.01098056434012, 
2.11756472024207, 3.84945595342866, 1.65771847121757, 1.66183209049326, 
4.18010042506516, 1.88868015453788, 2.47729343641235, 1.8515527897761, 
1.801989691278, 0.960679082279449, 1.90713452632661, 1.67162644481073, 
0.651194871722673, 2.20934211645569, 1.55541802527236, 2.3951259886822, 
2.11859438827037, 0.876173629956539, 1.01684797501249, 1.47655794370892, 
2.60015293290814, 3.51656554383228, 1.9386258392169, 1.13569078381674, 
1.79939892819708, 0.986783261979794, 1.34318659662266, 1.51513860367455, 
1.98002250044738, 2.11199891810736, 1.57300940771874, 0.795910392744986, 
2.30228194075246, 0.899752504242746, 1.35429176710988, 1.91580766945017, 
2.29875466800376, 1.38520416491655, 1.45570771342962), v4 = c(8.71125165472984, 
6.32881408777085, 7.80565264526579, 7.43471867416092, 9.94049739802176, 
9.20947019293676, 8.1664770081813, 9.07857667038051, 8.49126632046115, 
7.55216781855327, 9.84954569744894, 8.27475241237888, 8.41120674167834, 
10.0524425495767, 6.5192068797046, 8.1873900980587, 10.3524609959573, 
9.94168402317905, 11.0297176203143, 5.65849962891225, 9.24953635203077, 
5.53567031302534, 9.04105640376252, 6.91262423685684, 9.60358524564422, 
9.45927309289596, 10.1462189990831, 10.3283640381791, 9.83123701385966, 
11.9680627077076, 8.31541232685371, 9.02070010102381, 10.0085046609395, 
7.21457356625473, 9.59986471183621, 10.9880808749318, 9.93873461573387, 
8.73651424531762, 10.4528800675397, 6.30184824646523, 6.72172360693873, 
10.49496041726, 8.33723621174412, 9.11722325867205, 9.10894904505431, 
5.94520664144713, 7.01067293871772, 11.0903428088962, 8.98914754689884, 
9.96343095393113, 8.36600221010689, 6.46571738631721, 8.13581653793091, 
6.88539354313762, 10.4962932198444, 10.2753200349113, 5.99779535265748, 
5.46122416964871, 12.0687179733015, 11.4615742395565, 8.13788871397296, 
9.83102338435623, 7.80746891410811, 7.6172063856036, 5.05713287808634, 
8.30329187316045, 7.10815225276937, 8.07993354772719, 9.59148857137835, 
8.23943775825001, 9.89470640444116, 8.65883516996781), v5 = c(0.129707473089592, 
0.885962997075058, 0.168707654840976, 0.278078562089611, 0.227782667605751, 
0.132103910222261, 0.236165606517276, 0.127307570028682, 0.239131032260462, 
0.166795796005849, 0.150083556690961, 0.515845396429622, 0.333839383992952, 
0.220996616701815, 0.813732420477946, 0.393321778068206, 0.300335409725943, 
0.660321038547552, 0.394313430920244, 0.729724827428498, 0.153441493289325, 
0.611641151112884, 0.116851646647415, 0.376686857121094, 0.0806763142266202, 
0.213050025487081, 0.272008008099302, 0.338954055251426, 0.167848645788905, 
0.526045465907291, 0.368862884842483, 0.130165152672217, 0.59027087278628, 
0.153326262275859, 0.236240867963887, 0.564185817363237, 0.231631351126843, 
0.12717245001184, 0.373638473806822, 0.885380859825906, 0.115871749885622, 
0.367369123814891, 0.177096821114144, 0.0978870314767993, 0.097830836652513, 
0.951150429198077, 0.133102049346793, 0.426520453002122, 0.130084176247668, 
0.226231424779936, 0.332755326119385, 0.742991462828791, 0.24128567397987, 
0.356342655471471, 0.305663471673577, 0.265946085757078, 0.913914000973627, 
0.975642257166734, 0.513286304811347, 0.524191145043918, 0.384878728781288, 
0.23173893633778, 0.144623038144242, 0.403850175263561, 0.539830538053822, 
0.330983367839019, 0.220332336871917, 0.158271914638682, 0.204654025097371, 
0.303067378610063, 0.100487127525523, 0.24004553701393), v6 = c(16.6666666666667, 
6, 25.25, 2.44444444444444, 30.25, 9.5, 17.8181818181818, 20.9, 
21, 22.1111111111111, 9.3, 5.23076923076923, 20.25, 15.75, 6.125, 
6.6, 18.5, 13.3076923076923, 10.875, 6.71428571428571, 23, 6.5, 
22.75, 17.3125, 7.85714285714286, 17.3333333333333, 15.75, 7, 
8.75, 20.2, 6.08333333333333, 18.8, 10.6666666666667, 16.25, 
23.3, 11.2857142857143, 26.5, 1, 13.8, 11.3333333333333, 24.75, 
19, 14.375, 9.5, 11.1818181818182, 9.57142857142857, 24.9166666666667, 
11, 23.75, 22, 8.47368421052632, 2.5, 4.54545454545455, 15.8571428571429, 
13.8571428571429, 25, 2, 9.5, 10.3076923076923, 25, 12.6, 34, 
16.75, 2, 5.25, 12.6, 3.5, 10.9285714285714, 20.2, 17.9285714285714, 
8.5, 21.5), v7 = c(1.15402802325663, 0.423319922188671, 0.352289521121009, 
1.76985888678218, 1.08191544095076, 0.340002567224491, 0.00763634228410321, 
2.22994594682717, 0.825026773147924, 0.838790173469911, 0.00555951560051694, 
0.296134031596756, 1.51272599539085, 0.397742595200757, 0.034898764883907, 
0.00568622204238151, 0.063107203669822, 0.131983300937987, 0.00114565556515586, 
1.36135196574796, 1.2391139295848, 1.30406728295154, 1.16025467503577, 
0.00290709229964781, 0.267295800473671, 1.35025052103336, 0.0349086306815228, 
0.00435102002699408, 0.00554027600117536, 1.00900396772844, 0.00948093068442497, 
0.37325399072092, 0.998967650877022, 0.0396626515518179, 0.951107790541739, 
0.000899371073464541, 0.220891986928299, 0.0142926404720385, 
0.00434998121232176, 0.276279112853656, 0.0238435901920359, 0.00435169204899019, 
0.146204873768018, 0.000353738352021244, 0.000353738343753515, 
0.00493503455692317, 1.67478943554035, 0.0806290814278405, 2.42996653450033, 
0.0580910956908263, 0.0156589679508425, 0.0110230581585001, 1.96804476174753, 
0.0154930870916259, 0.0626461532781184, 0.210170279919954, 0.01140693066167, 
0.0114145421222131, 2.16367104376351, 1.23026251852254, 0.318178960594407, 
0.98760041631224, 0.000580657310588349, 0.00816050118418013, 
0.277371981991339, 0.00373394289797588, 0.000556181502835084, 
0.759067690667071, 0.7348597334175, 0.00373316033740552, 0.0579734476698544, 
0.521069699428444), v8 = c(0.0435888790117402, 0.175378534414342, 
0.074664176979982, 0.224229737134187, 0.101268008417418, 0.0348710763054625, 
0.192976636217782, 0.0800723974740007, 0.0642706794326465, 0.0319428143398315, 
0.0293529927638666, 0.281569244864285, 0.377651867790403, 0.497872575129615, 
0.470858219441047, 0.333638769074631, 0.470466049191276, 0.241623711340206, 
0.016855687653788, 0.0885135558479454, 0.057219941801083, 0.146111364714517, 
0.0691311017415475, 0.20837456140787, 0.142352661879043, 0.026123898569633, 
0.483785431757453, 0.00507443841549662, 0.00178941129829929, 
0.246541796280363, 0.0863295821447604, 0.0964480165932072, 0.47468112777559, 
0.133754509140892, 0.22037244594094, 0.066233907702581, 0.37393021724819, 
0.00108704837557329, 0.0547027124937735, 0.00394733404738891, 
0.00254686851959711, 0.0431846696021161, 0.00449405885419475, 
0.00175590055749843, 0.00175057964671813, 0.275758231624117, 
0.460326677684966, 0.071506357629839, 0.400699908184442, 0.227491648392187, 
0.265502592960388, 0.0222769930799128, 0.479988594330432, 0.244791200929983, 
0.124976018856031, 0.474775150768974, 0.221421792770253, 0.214059295170613, 
0.0478631173731447, 0.178092876922854, 0.497707329873203, 0.131778877690977, 
0.0108377097753295, 0.0631038953717797, 0.0145958766648422, 0.0398573975044563, 
0.0160714860385535, 0.0124908871882639, 0.0235661555934128, 0.0114081996434938, 
0.04930797745169, 0.0392002499218994), v9 = c(0.00417048, 0.00117287, 
0.00313865, 0.04717076, 0.00135412, 0.01561571, 0.00001, 0.00095716, 
0.00506926, 0.00150023, 0.00252461, 0.00577162, 0.00076085, 0.00099518, 
0.05609756, 0.00298906, 0.00091081, 0.00132289, 0.00046762, 0.00408977, 
0.00228687, 0.0020811, 0.00308264, 0.00405877, 0.00119809, 0.00540178, 
0.00001, 0.00179562, 0.00451327, 0.00077276, 0.00714198, 0.00096252, 
0.00156651, 0.0065056, 0.00173053, 0.00101645, 0.00001, 0.00249165, 
0.00455664, 0.00026613, 0.00001, 0.00086245, 0.00330209, 0.00693899, 
0.00946316, 0.00169825, 0.00035265, 0.00200707, 0.00001, 0.00008891, 
0.0027758, 0.01845959, 0.003375, 0.00183504, 0.00075968, 0.00009525, 
0.0365298, 0.00865962, 0.00031374, 0.00121338, 0.00101544, 0.00095639, 
0.00097537, 0.0112433, 0.00591904, 0.00003496, 0.01970091, 0.0216232, 
0.00001, 0.00100665, 0.01177993, 0.00683953), v10 = c(1.66788432267884, 
1.60109589041096, 1.50068493150685, 2.55738203957382, 1.7513698630137, 
1.75068493150685, 1.54645080946451, 1.50109589041096, 3.50228310502283, 
1.33424657534247, 2.40164383561644, 1.92434141201264, 2.0013698630137, 
1.91803652968037, 1.25102739726027, 1.80109589041096, 1.25068493150685, 
1.92434141201264, 2.3763698630137, 1.71545988258317, 1.00068493150685, 
2.1013698630137, 1.37602739726027, 1.43852739726027, 1.85831702544031, 
0.833789954337899, 1.7513698630137, 2.89071537290715, 2.2513698630137, 
1.80164383561644, 1.33424657534247, 2.00164383561644, 1.4175799086758, 
0.750684931506849, 1.20082191780822, 1.57240704500978, 2.25205479452055, 
1.60109589041096, 3.00219178082192, 2.50182648401826, 1.00068493150685, 
3.6689497716895, 1.12568493150685, 2.7513698630137, 1.36463262764633, 
2.28727984344423, 1.25091324200913, 1.85831702544031, 1.7513698630137, 
3.20219178082192, 1.36928622927181, 1.7513698630137, 2.00124533001245, 
1.28649706457926, 1.71545988258317, 2.0013698630137, 1.33424657534247, 
1.25068493150685, 1.69357218124341, 1.77899543378995, 2.20109589041096, 
1.4175799086758, 3.00205479452055, 1.60109589041096, 2.75205479452055, 
2.60164383561644, 1.7513698630137, 1.21506849315068, 1.40109589041096, 
1.21506849315068, 0.750684931506849, 1.50091324200913), v11 = c(8L, 
4L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 
3L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 13L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 
4L, 11L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 
11L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 18L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 12L, 8L, 
4L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 32L, 36L, 
37L, 40L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 56L, 59L, 62L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 
73L, 77L, 80L, 84L, 87L, 88L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 104L, 106L, 107L, 110L, 111L, 115L, 116L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 
128L, 129L, 131L, 134L, 137L, 141L, 144L, 145L, 148L, 152L, 153L, 
157L, 158L, 162L, 163L, 167L, 169L, 171L, 173L, 176L, 179L, 182L
))
```

Comment: Please ask an admin to move this to SO.  The CV folks will downvote without explanation for code-centric questions.

Comment: someone there said to post here :(

Comment: I've been in those loops.  no fun.  Might put a line in the top such as "migrated from SO, they said CV was a good place to get the answer".  Might also say something like "trying to understand what it means in terms my grandma might understand".